# Multiple flow startup very slow after upgrading from 3.1.2 to 3.3.0

Tags: performance, jboss, startup, esb, mule

We recently upgraded from Mule 3.1.2 to 3.3.0. 
We are using Mule deployed inside a war in JBoss 5.1. 
On our backoffice application we have a large number of flows using a quartz inbound endpoint then running various processors. like this one :

```
<flow name="ImportXXX">
    <quartz:inbound-endpoint repeatInterval="5000" startDelay="10000" jobName="QuartzImportXXX" >
        <quartz:event-generator-job>
            <quartz:payload>${XXX.depot} | ${archive}</quartz:payload>
        </quartz:event-generator-job>
    </quartz:inbound-endpoint>
    <component>
       ...
    </component>
    <component>
    ...
    </component>
</flow>
```

We have about 40 flows similar to this one (processor does different things depending on the quartz payload)

With mule 3.3.0, each of these flow take about 5s to start, with the exact same configuration on 3.1.2 flows were starting instantly (less than 1/10s per flow). We did not change anything to the underlying processors implementation neither, this was a pure migration. 
I tried to remove all our specific processors, and replace them with a single one which does nothing but log one line. Now the startup of each flow is "reduced" to 1.5s, but still a lot slower than with 3.1.2. 
Overall the problem grows with the number of flows and component loaded (If I comment half of the flows, the single flow startup time is improved by 1 or 2s)

This seems to be specific when deployed in a war in JBoss, I tried the exact same mule-config.xml in a standalone Mule app created from a basic maven archetype and all flows starts smoothly and quickly as in 3.1.2.

Is there any change in the way flows are initialized in Mule 3.3 which could explain this ? 
Any idea about what I could check or try ?

Thanks for your help,

Laurent

Comment: Some other member of the community have been experiencing the same problem, and it seems somehow to be related to the AnnotationsParserFactory not being found in the registry. It would be great if you could file a jira with a simple test case to reproduce it.

Comment: I filed the issue in JIRA http://www.mulesoft.org/jira/browse/MULE-6461. There is a sample project attached as well as the JBoss startup log (with both Mule 3.1.2 and 3.3.0)

Comment: I also noticed this log when Mule starts up on JBoss (in both 3.1.2 and 3.3.0): [DecoratingAnnotatedServiceProcessor] org.mule.config.AnnotationsParserFactory implementation not found in registry, annotations not enabled. 
Which looks like what you're saying.